# What's the difference between /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and /etc/apache2/httpd.conf?

Tags: apache-2.2

Is httpd.conf the name of the configuration file for older apache versions?  Are there certain directives you are expected to use in one as opposed to the other?

I'm learning how to password protect directories and noticed that including the appropriate directives in either httpd.conf or apache2.conf get the job done just the same.  However http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/howto/auth.html seems to only mention to include password protection directives in httpd.conf.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you're refering to Ubuntu or Debian since they usually use this syntax of configuration files. If you look at the bottom part of `apache2.conf` you will see that it includes `httpd.conf`. You can read Ubuntu's explanation of what the files are meant to do at this URL:
https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/httpd.html